# kakfa mock registry for testing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

so i have set up in my spring properties file:

```
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=mock://localhost
```

But when i run the test i get the following

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro unknown schema for id 1
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.toKafkaException(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:259)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:341)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:113)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:201)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject Not Found; error code: 40401
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndIdFromRegistry(MockSchemaRegistryClient.java:177)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(MockSchemaRegistryClient.java:262)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:330)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

used which worked:

```
private MockSchemaRegistryClient mockSchemaRegistryClient = new MockSchemaRegistryClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to define a mocked function response when ID 1 is requested, otherwise your mock is just a stub and has no schemas registered to lookup by a consumer, in this case

You may instead want to try this library - https://github.com/bakdata/fluent-kafka-streams-tests/tree/master/schema-registry-mock